# Cannot keep submenu open after clicking one of its items

Tags: jquery, html, click, submenu

I am using jquery click function to display a submenu when a menu item is clicked.  I wish the submenu to remain opened after I click one of its items until I return to another item in main menu.  I have tried multiple solutions, read multiple posts and bought a book on jquery and not finding an answer.  I suspect problem is that when an li within a ul is clicked, it is not possible to change the display of the encapsulating ul.  But here is my most recent code try.
(Any help would really be appreciated.  I'm about to give up and just have the menus all displayed by taking out the display:hide in the css.  But figured I'd see if someone here can answer this question.)

Pertinent Html:

```
     <div id="navbar">          

    <div style="margin-top:5em; margin-left:0em;">    
     <ul class = "nav-level1">
        <li class="nosub"><a href="index.php?content=bethhome" title="Go to home page">Home</a></li>
      <li class="parent"> <a href = "#" >About Us</a>   
            <ul class="nav-level2">
                <li class="nav-whoweare"><a href ="index.php?content=whoweare" title="Who We Are">Who We Are</a></li> 
                <li class="nav-whoweare"><a href ="index.php?content=ourmission" title="Our Mission and Values">Our Mission and Values</a></li> 
                <li class="nav-whoweare"><a href ="index.php?content=ourhistory" title="Our History">Our History</a></li> 
                <li class="parent2"><a href = "#">Our Interim Pastors</a>
                   <ul class = "nav-level3">
                     <li class="nav-whoweare"><a href ="index.php?content=ourpastor" title="Rev. Charles Webb">Rev. Charles Webb</a></li> 
                     <li class="nav-whoweare"><a href ="index.php?content=ourpastor2" title="Vicar Daniel Dockery">Vicar Daniel Dockery</a></li> 

                    </ul>
                </li>                        

              </ul> 
            </li>     
          <li class="nosub"><a href="index.php?content=library" title="Our Library">Library</a></li>
          <li class="nosub"><a href="index.php?content=calendary" title="Calendar of Events">Calendar of Events</a></li>
          <li class="nosub"><a href="index.php?content=missions" title="Our Mission Work">Our Mission Work</a></li>
          <li class="nosub"><a href="index.php?content=ouractivities" title="Our Activities, Groups and Events">Our Activities</a></li>    

    </ul>                                                                         
    </div> <br />
```

My CSS code:

```
#navbar ul.nav-level2, #navbar ul.nav-level3
{
   font-size:.8em;
   display:none;
} 

#navbar ul.nav-level2 li
{
  margin-left:1em;  
}

} 
 #navbar ul.nav-level3 li
{
  margin-left:2em;
}
```

My jquery scripts:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function(event) {
      $('.nav-level2').show();
    });
});
</script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nosub').click(function(event) {
       $('.nav-level3').hide();
       $('.nav-level2').hide();
     });
});
</script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent2').click(function(event) {
       $('.nav-level3').show();
       $('.nav-level2').show();
     });
});
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">    //testng script
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-whoweare').click(function(event) {

        $'.nav-level2'}.show();
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full with typos. Please be more careful.. and don't forget to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3vzffvn/1/) and use debugger (Google Crome's built in debugger for ex.)

besides, [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is more appropiate

here is your working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').hover(
        function() {
            $('.nav-level2').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('.nav-level2').hide();
        }
    );
    $('.parent2').hover(
        function() {
            $('.nav-level3').show();
            $('.nav-level2').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('.nav-level3').hide();
            $('.nav-level2').hide();
        }
    );

    $('.nav-whoweare').hover(
        function() {
            $('.nav-level2').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('.nav-level2').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I thought that hover should not be used because of the problem with mobiles not responding well and that click should be used instead.

Comment: you can use hover on desktop and touch events on mobile